# Design breakable PCB for power distribution bus

Tags: power, pcb-design, bus, via

I am trying to design a PCB for power distribution bus to clean up wiring mess when prototyping.

Here's my plan:

- Long PCB with single trace for each copper plane.
- Put pads to distribute power along the trace: 5.08mm pitch for high current version and 2.54mm pitch pads for low current version.
- Make some breakpoints to adjust length of bus by breaking the PCB.

This is a general purpose PCB to use when prototyping so I cannot assure the maximum voltage or current but I work with low DC voltage under 20V and current upto 10A usually.

To make breakpoints, I am considering consecutive vias or small size of pads instead of plain hole because they are conductive.

1. Is this feasible plan?
2. Even though vias or pads are conductive, it makes holes anyway, so it will reduce trace width effectively. For instance, in a row of 5 vias whose diameter is 0.3mm, it will reduce the trace width by 1.5mm and lower conductance. Am I correct?
3. Is there better design for general purpose power distribution PCB?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

This is somewhat I think now:

[image]

Comment: For prototyping, I use vias. Just place a row of them of reasonable diameter and spacing which your PCB fab is happy about and its job done. Should _plain_ be plane per chance? Plain copper? A copper plane?

Comment: @winny copper plane, plane of ground plane, yes. I always mistype though. Thank you! Could you recommend start point of reasonable diameter and spacing? I have no clue now.

Comment: One important point is: Which components will be on this PCB at the time you plan to break it?

Comment: @asdfex I don't think there is any component laying on this PCB directly. It will mainly power to other PCB through pin header and sometimes wires could be directly soldered on pads on the PCB.

Comment: Can you add a quick sketch of what you are thinking of?  I see several possibilities and do not have any idea of exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The PCB will not break cleanly if you use plated-through holes for mouse bites. And the copper traces can peel back. Maybe you can use a component of some kind (eg. 0Ω resistor) to jump the break points.

Comment: @DwayneReid I've added a picture describing what I am thinking.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Honestly, I didn't notice about that. Do you mean that it would be better to make PCB broken at the very first and connect them later to extend?

Answer (score 1):

To break a PCB in production, there are essentially 3 technique usually used.

The first is the most expensive an least used, is to make a custom holder for your PCB and cut it before production. Probably not a possibility here.

The second is V grooving. V grooves are usually a mark made of a depth of 1/3 of your PCB on both size. These allows to easily break the PCB. There main advantages are that they are cheap and fast. There main flaw is that they must be done in a straight line for the whole length of the board.

The third option are mouse bite. These are small holes, usually unplatted, in a row of around 5 holes placed at several location of the board. These allow for custom shape.

To pass signal on V grooved board, usually, you can't since both outer and inner layer are cut in the process. The only way to pass a signal is by placing vias on the V groove path that are significantly wider then the Vgroove so the metal in the via (in the middle) will remain and make a connection. This is fine for programming signals and low power DC, but 10A would never work!

To pass signal on mouse bite, usually, you pass between the bites. This allow for more copper and will allow greater current. That being said, 10A is still significant.

On both technique, to pass larger signals, people will often use beds of nails or similar setups to provide the power from a board bellow. This might be your best option for such current.

Good luck!

Comment: Basically, my idea is identical with mouse bites using vias instead of plain hole for better conductance under not-broken-intact situation. Also, with untented vias, I think I can somewhat compensate conductance and mechanical strength by adding solders over vias.

Comment: I never done that! So I would make a test batch first to see. But I would be worried that the via rips out instead of breaking. If that happens, you might rip the track off the board. Maybe placing a second via on your PCB to limit the peeling of the trace. I can't see your design, but  maybe you can place some jumper that you desolder prior to breaking?

Comment: Adding solder is just an potential improvement which I thought I can apply when I need. Could you elaborate on jumper thing? Do you mean connecting broken parts by jumper and break the PCB by removing the jumper?

Comment: No, my idea was, since you already have to assemble the board, maybe you could add a 0ohm resistor over your mouse bite. Let say you use a 2512 resistor has a bridge, they can dissipate about 1W and pass around 5A. If you solder 2 of these, it would handle the 10A. To break them away, you take a heatgun and remove the jumpers than break it. It's a bit more painful process, but, if you don't have thousands of units, it should be quite cheap.

Comment: Regarding the solder, maybe it will help current pass. But, the main issue, is the breaking. Solder is quite hard and I doubt you'll never have a clean break.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you posted a picture. Hmmm. That wasn't what I had in mind. I think your issue will be dependent to the amount of units you need to assemble and where you break the PCB. Seeing the picture, your only option might be using an abrasive disk. But if you have any significant volume of production, it will be very painful and expensive.

Comment: Well I love the jumper idea but it is too big. With double 1oz copper layer, I can transfer 10A with only 4mm width track but two 2512 resistors occupy nearly 1cm.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming one single PCB strip per supply rail?

If so, make like you show in the picture but do NOT add drill holes to make it easier for you to snap the board to the desired length.  Instead, place a half-hole on each edge of the strip midway between the holes for the connectors.  It makes no sense to cut the strip at the connector holes.

These half-holes should be fairly small - say 0.025".

Then simply use a pair of side cutters to snip the board to the desired length.  The half-holes will help you guide you to cut at the proper location.